# SCons install throws no attribute error on the Scons module

Tags: python, scons

I used chocolatey to install python3.6 and SCons 3.0.0 on windows. But out of the box, it doesn't run.

```
File "C:\Python36\Scripts\scons.py", line 201, in <module>
SCons.Script.main()
File "C:\Python36\scons-3.0.0\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 13
parts.append(version_string("engine", SCons))
File "C:\Python36\scons-3.0.0\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 81
version = module.__version__
AttributeError: module 'SCons' has no attribute '__version__'
```

You can see the directory structure above, but for easy reading...

```
Python
  -scons.bat
  -Scripts
       -scons.py
  -scons-3.0.0
      -SCons
         -Script
            -Main.py
```

I'm new to Scons. The homepage says 3.0.0 is compatable with python 3.5+ but not *specifically* python 3.6. Is this a versions problem or an install issue?

Comment: What was the command line you used to run scons?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Scons 3.0.1 solved the issue for me, so a possible version issue.